# How to improve performance of an `INSERT INTO SELECT x FROM y GROUP BY z` MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have the following query which causes CPU usage to go to maximum (severely deteriorating the performance of everything else running on the server) and takes many minutes to run.

```
INSERT INTO cache (`time`, name, price, low, high, week, month, season)
SELECT
    MAX(`time`) AS `time`,
    name,
    MIN(CASE WHEN `time` = 1500254967 THEN price ELSE 999999 END) AS price,
    MIN(price) AS low,
    MAX(price) AS high,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > 1499650167 AND price = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > 1499650167 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > 1497835767 AND price = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > 1497835767 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > 1499995767 AND price = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > 1499995767 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS season
FROM low_price
GROUP BY name;
```

EXPLAIN tells me:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | low_price | index | idx_name      | idx_name | 603     | NULL | 20875117 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------+
```

which looks OK to my non-expert eye.

There are 12 million rows in the low_price table that is being selected from. Ideally this table should be allowed to grow from here but it's ok to prune it down to this size as a maximum. Making it smaller would entail losing data. We could go to fetching data once/day instead of once/hour to make it 1/24th the size but I would prefer not to if there's another way.

The table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE `low_price` (
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `cache` (
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `week` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `season` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This query does NOT run on user time. It's setting up the cache table that gets used on user time. So an alternative to the best option of speeding this up is just telling it "hey, don't use so much CPU". I'm a bit loathe to go that route because the time it takes is already so long that it would start to run into itself on the hourly runs.

Do you have any advice for me? Alternative styles of generating this table or things to look at to improve this particular INSERT? Thanks!

Comment: I'd try running it without the CASE statements and see how much of an improvement you get.

Comment: Thanks. Removing CASE didn't seem to help much for some reason. Possibly because MAX and MIN are still causing me to scan all that data? The index suggested in the answers below really helped.

Comment: @JeffUK - Fetching rows is, by far, the main part of any query.  And this query needs to fetch _all_ the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composite index on `(name, time, price)` will help, because it is a covering index.

I would also write the query as:

```
INSERT INTO cache (`time`, name, price, low, high, week, month, season)
    SELECT MAX(`time`) AS `time`,
           name,
           MIN(CASE WHEN `time` = 1500254967 THEN price END) AS price,
           MIN(price) AS low, MAX(price) AS high,
           AVG(CASE WHEN `time` > 1499650167 AND price = 1 THEN 1.0
                    WHEN `time` > 1499650167 THEN 0
               END) AS week,
           AVG(CASE WHEN `time` > 1497835767 AND price = 1 THEN 1.0
                    WHEN `time` > 1497835767 THEN 0.0
               END) AS month,
           AVG(CASE WHEN `time` > 1499995767 AND price = 1 THEN 1.0
                    WHEN `time` > 1499995767 THEN 0.0
               END) AS season
    FROM low_price
    GROUP BY name;
```

The changes will not help performance much; I just think `AVG()` is simpler than two `SUM()`s, and I don't like having arbitrary values such as 999999 sitting around.

Comment: Totally agree about 999999. Neat elision.

Comment: Your rewrite of the query to use AVG (thanks for pointing that out, doh!) seems to save about another 15% of the time after the big gains from the index. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be precise, but I would try to define one more (of course not primary key) index on low_price table with the following Keys:

```
name,
time,
price
```

This could help the subqueries based on time and price.
Remind, Keys order in indexes are important.

Comment: Awesome! EXPLAIN told me it still chose to use the index on name but after I drop that it gets about 5x faster! :D

It would be really great if you could explain how you worked out that the fields are looked at in that order for the index?

Comment: name is used first for the GROUP BY clause, then time is used for the aggregate functions inside every group, and in particular will improve the MAX and MIN functions. Just for curiosity you could Exchange time and price, and see what's best.

Comment: Thanks! Seemed very close but slightly slower with the second one.

Comment: Production speedup looks more like 16x!

Comment: When timing a query, run it twice -- the first run may have to fetch stuff from disk; the second will have as much cached as practical.  Quote the second time.

Answer (score 1):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of *available* RAM.  Below that, you may be I/O-bound (10x slower).  Over that, you risk swapping (which is even worse).

You could shrink the dataset to save space, therefor cut down on I/O.

- `DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes -- overkill.  Instead, use `FLOAT` (4 bytes) which has 7-digit percision.
- `INT` takes 4 bytes, and is overkill; no ticker goes beyond 16M does it?  `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` is 3 bytes and allows 0..16M.  Have you lopped off the decimal part?  If you want the fractions, then `FLOAT` might be best.
- Ticker symbols are all ascii and certainly not 150 characters.  Perhaps 8 max?  Even if this is the full name, 'normalize' the names into another table and `JOIN` on ticker symbol.
- InnoDB really needs a unique `PRIMARY KEY`.  For `low_price`, it should probably be `PRIMARY KEY(name, time)`, then toss `KEY(name)` as being redundant.  `cache` might need the same.

I am bothered by the timestamps in the query.  They seem to be random times like `2017-07-09 18:29:27`.  Don't you want to reach back from top of the hour?

And, are there really 24 hours in a day?  The markets close a lot.

After you have fixed up those, we can discuss how to write a Summary Table that lets you get rid of `cache` and do the query live!

Comment: Thanks! Market is 24 hours – for Magic cards. The names can be up to LENGTH('Our Market Research Shows That Players Like Really Long Card Names So We Made this Card to Have the Absolute Longest Card Name Ever Elemental') but a unique substring would be smaller. Some names have diacritics. Timestamps are "time of last run", "a week before", "a month before" and "start of the season" (a fixed date - changes every quarter). For DOUBLE I don't need hardly any precision - one decimal place? Could I save more there? Store as a small integer of some kind? I'll try the primary key thing. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I made a wrong assumption.  Still normalization of `name` is wise.

Comment: `DECIMAL(7,1)` takes 4 bytes; what is the largest number you can have? May as well go with `FLOAT` at 4 bytes, with a max of about 10^38.

Comment: Awesome. While these obviously didn't have the huge impact of getting the right index I did get a total of 12.5% speedup on local from implementing them all. It didn't seem to have as much of an effect on prod which takes 45s currently. Is a summary table still appropriate?

Comment: Before digging into summary tables,...  How many rows are there per day per card-name?  If many per day, then summarize per day into a single table.  If 1/day, then separate summaries per week and month.  How do you define "season"?

Comment: There's 24 low prices/day per card. One for every time the data-gathering program runs. Season is a specific date roughly every 3 months. So sometimes it's very recent, never much more than 3 months. You're right that I never rollup to less than a day so a day table would make a lot of sense. Thanks!